# mySQL tables & queries

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I was wondering, I know that it is better to have tables with around 20 columns and so. So, lets take an example like a game server with a mySQL database for saving players stats and have every system structured on different tables (cars, houses, stats and so on) but if I have like 60 stats that I need to save (that goes to the user table) it's better to keep it like that or to cut some of the stats from user table and move them into a new table and make a new query just to load from that table.

So my question, to make more tables low in columns and a little more queries or to keep more columns in some tables and have less queries?

Comment: There is no rule that says that tables with 20 columns are better or worse than other tables.

Comment: If the goal is to develop an online game, I suggest to have a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560426/what-database-do-online-games-like-farmville-use

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can sort them in different table base on the themes Eg. Stats like str, dex, int, luck on a table and Assets on another table but both table must have a column which is identical to the user ID or something so as when required you can always inner join the tables to see the overall/specific status of a certain user.

Answer (score 0):

this answer may not target your case specifically since i did not quite understand the relation between users and stats, maybe if you show us some example of your current database we can help you more.

but one thing is sure, if you have a lot of null values in your tables then you can do a better schema, the more you split your data into tables the more it gets easy to control it.

[image]

the above schema shows the relation between users and statistic, so the user table hold only users data, and the statistic table hold only statistic data, the relation between those 2 tables is in an other table that assign a statistic to a user, this way you tables are specific and flexible.

hope it helps